# Explanation of console log output in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic

Can anyone explain to me each of the terms appearing in this line from the Weblogic console log file?

Specifically the usernames that appear **wlsuser** and **charn** - are these Weblogic console users or Unix usernames?

> 11/05/23 21:11:06 oram01 wls01
>   WLSPW0090 INFO wlsuser 3967 Server
>   admin_01 stop request accepted
>
> 11/05/25 09:42:13 oram01 
>   WLPNG0020 INFO charn 18408
>   Pinging server managed2_01 using
>   URL t3://147.100.100.100:6100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've been able to confirm that **wlsuser** and **charn** are the *unix* users who login to the machine.